# Accessing Minecraft Terminal when it's ran through systemmd

Tags: systemd, minecraft

New to Linux but have been messing around with a Linode server. I am running a Paper Minecraft server as a systemd unit file. This way my server can be 24/7 without me having to keep my terminal session open. Normally when you run the server manually with "java -jar paper.jar" it'll lead you right into that server's terminal. However, since it is being run automatically by the minecraft.service unit file I don't have access. How would I get into that service's minecraft terminal? The service is running and the server is running.

EDIT: I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on my Linode

Comment: Minecraft has a RCON terminal that you can enable

Answer (score 1):

You could change your command to run the service under Screen, and connect to that if needed, or enable RCON in your configuration.